# iPhone / iPad SDK - Joining two or more videos together

Tags: iphone, ipad, video, sdk

Does anyone know if it's possible to join two or more videos together using the iPhone SDK? Also, I can get the videos in any format if that is going to be an issue.

Comment: What do you mean by JOIN?, put one after another? or put one frame next to other?(so each frame size will increase), blending frames?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yup: the `AVFoundation` framework has the `AVComposition` class, which does exactly that.